# Aggregate cover_me results for rspec and cucumber

Tags: rspec, cucumber, code-coverage

Before moving over to ruby 1.9.2 and cover_me I was using rcov. We don't tend to unit test controllers, relying instead on cucumber coverage. With rcov it was possible to aggregate the coverage results from both the cucumber and rspec runs. Is this possible with cover_me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the Rakefile that I ended up with, you can get coverage for rspec, cucumber or both combined:

```
namespace :cover_me do
  task :report do
    require 'cover_me'
    CoverMe.complete!
  end

  task :all => %w{ rake:spec rake:cucumber report }
  task :spec => %w{ rake:spec report }
  task :cucumber => %w{ rake:cucumber report }
end
```

Comment: Using cover_me https://github.com/markbates/cover_me and the above rake file is the easiest way to get code coverage for cucumber up and running on rails3 & ruby 1.9.